# I am trying to use JPA in my servlet project but i am unsable to do so i am getting error that my repository is null i am unable to fix this problem

Tags: java, spring, jpa, servlets, spring-repositories

Here is my servlet code

```
package com.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Configurable;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.SpringBeanAutowiringSupport;

import jakarta.servlet.ServletConfig;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@Configuration
public class DoGet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;


    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {

super.init(config);
SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);
    }


    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
TODO Auto-generated method stub


String search = "%"+request.getParameter("search")+"%";
List<Product> findByProductNameLike = productRepository.findByProductNameLike(search);

PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
writer.write("<h1>Hello World How are You<h1>");

for(Product i: findByProductNameLike)
{
    writer.write(i.getProductId());
    writer.write(i.getProductName());
    writer.write(i.getImgPath());
}

    writer.write("<h1>Done<h1>");
 }

}
```

This is my productRepository

```
package com.servlet;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, String>{
    
    public List<Product> findByProductNameLike(String produtName);

}
```

I have tried creating object of one other class since I thought ProductRepository is an interface so I might be getting an error.

I was expecting a proper output on the window, instead I am getting error message that productRepository is null on line

```
List<Product> findByProductNameLike = productRepository.findByProductNameLike(search);
```

Here is the proper error message:

```
Type Exception Report

Message Cannot invoke "com.servlet.ProductRepository.findByProductNameLike(String)" because "this.productRepository" is null

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.servlet.ProductRepository.findByProductNameLike(String)" because "this.productRepository" is null
    com.servlet.DoGet.doGet(DoGet.java:40)
    jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:683)
    jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:792)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

I am using Apache Tomcat v10.0. I have looked at many tutorials and solutions to other questions, but still wasn't able to run my code in the desired way.

I wasn't able to post applicationContext.xml and web.xml due to spam issues.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the DoGet is not a bean/component. So add @Component or @Configuration (maybe this was a typo here?) to it and then everything should be autowired correctly.

Comment: i tried changing the annotations but still the error message is same productRepository is still null it may be because of something wrong in applicationContext.xml file which i was unable to post here due to spamming issues.

Comment: did you register the DoGet  as a bean in the applicationContext.xml file? Do you use spring boot? Which version? EDIT: try to replace it with @_Component instead of @_Configuration

Comment: <context:component-scan base-package="com.servlet"></context:component-scan>
 <context:annotation-config />
 <context:spring-configured />

 <bean id="productRepository" class="com.servlet.ProductRepository" />
 <bean id="product" class="com.servlet.Product" />

this is my applicationContext.xml file could you tell me how would i register DoGet as a bean

Comment: <bean id="DoGet" class="com.servlet.DoGet" /> but tbh you should use annotation based spring instead of relying on the applicationContext.xml file

Comment: i have added it as a bean but still no progress same error message.

Comment: if you create a simple bean, can you inject the repository? You need to figure out if the bean exists or not. If yes, then figure out why its not loaded into your class. If no, you have not setup jpa correctly up

Comment: I am getting this error message in my console

02:39:07.752 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] WARN org.springframework.web.context.support.SpringBeanAutowiringSupport -- Current WebApplicationContext is not available for processing of GetServlet: Make sure this class gets constructed in a Spring web application after the Spring WebApplicationContext has been initialized. Proceeding without injection.